# Horizontal scroll Text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to display a long text on one line without clipping or ellipsing on a flutter web application. To do so, I want to make it horizontally scrollable. I have found this code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-scrollable-text/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    //adding App Bar
    appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(15, 157, 88, 1),
        title: Text(
        "GeeksForGeeks",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
        ),
        ),
    ),
    body: MyApp(),
    ),
));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
    child: Container(
        // adding margin
        
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        // adding padding
        
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            
        // adding borders around the widget
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            width: 5.0,
        ),
        ),
        // SingleChildScrollView should be
        // wrapped in an Expanded Widget
        child: Expanded(
            
        //contains a single child which is scrollable
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            
            //for horizontal scrolling
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Text(
            "GeeksForGeeks is a good platform to learn programming."
            " It is an educational website.",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 3,
                wordSpacing: 3,
            ),
            ),
        ),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}
```

But it didn't work for me.The text was clipped but not scrollable. I tried to add `overflow: TextOverflow.visible` to the Text widget but without result.I don't have any other idea because wrapping a `Text` in a `SingleChildScrollView` is the easiest thing I can think about for this problem.

Comment: Your code is working fine and it's scrollable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is happening because of `Expanded` widget. Remove this and it will work just fine,

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        // adding margin

        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        // adding padding

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // adding borders around the widget
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),

        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          //for horizontal scrolling
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Text(
            "GeeksForGeeks is a good platform to learn programming."
            " It is an educational website.",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.green,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              letterSpacing: 3,
              wordSpacing: 3,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for flutter to detect items under a scroll, you have to use ListView as of now. Add a listview widget and under that keep your text or other widgets and essentially flutter will detect your scroll widgets perfectly.

in **ListView** widget theres a property called **scrollDirection:** and you can set the value to **Axis.horizontal**, that does the trick.

For further references please check this out : [How to create a horizontal list in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list)

tip : avoid geeksforgeeks on the go for learning flutter, learned it the hard way